# Adding nodes to a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is simple adding nodes to linked list. I'm not able to figure out why the head pointer is being set to null with every call to add function.

```
//struct declaration of node
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
};

//adding node to the head pointer
void add_node(node* head, int d)
{
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->data = d;
    temp->next = NULL;
    node* tmp = head;
    if (tmp != NULL) {
        cout << "shal";
        while (tmp->next != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = temp;
    }
    else {
        //cout<<temp->data;
        head = temp;
    }
    cout << "dh" << head->data;
}


int main()
{
    node* head = NULL;
    // calling the add function
    add_node(head, 10);
    // head is being taken as null here
    add_node(head, 20);
}
```

Output:

`dh10nulldh20null`

Please help me in understanding where it went wrong.

Comment: You have a global `head` and a parameter `head`? Eww. Stop using globals for one thing.

Comment: You need to understand the difference in behavior of pass by value and pass by reference.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't get what a pointer is.

```
void plus_one(int num) {
    num += 1;
}

int main() {
    int num = 42;
    plus_one(num);
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

Obviously, `num` is still 42. Why? Because in function `plus_one` you get `num` by copy.

When you call your `add_node`, you send a copy of your `head` pointer. Since it is a pointer, you can modify what is POINTED BY the pointer, NOT the pointer itself. What you do is the same thing as trying to get `43` with my example... It's not possible if you are getting a copy.

You need to pass the address of your pointer, so call your function as it : `add_node(&head, 10);` and write your prototype as it : `void add_node(node** head,int d)`. You will have to modify your function to fit with your new `node**`.

Why does it work? Because you modify the content of the pointer which is POINTING TO you original pointer (which is POINTING TO your structure).